# Удаление фрагмента созданного при помощи replace

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Заполняю контейнер фрагментом так:

```
fManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.stage_container, MyFragment.class, args).commit();
```

Как после этого очистить контейнер? Ведь ни `id`, ни других признаков, которые позволили бы его однозначно определить в этом случае нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если необходимо просто очистить контейнер:

```
for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!